# Anyone ever seen this magento import images error?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I was importing some images and I came accross this error, curious if anyone had a clue to what it is since I cannot search for someone else with the same error.

[image]

Comment: You are not uploading correct format of csv file.

Comment: I'm using excel 2016 and I do my best to make sure there are no empty columns and delete unnecessary columns/cells to make sure the dataflow is correct as I know how sensitive these CSV files can be...

So far i'm 2k products out of 12k and fixing the session expired so far is working! Fingers crossed!

Curious if you guys use a diff CSV editor than excel?

Comment: Good to hear it works so far :-) You can also try 'magmi' for fast imports

Comment: Yeah I've heard about magmi, I'm going to have to check it out one day cheers and I will edit my answers when I reach 100% hehe

Answer (score 0):

It seems that that's the HTML of your admin login panel.

My guess is that your session expired during export. Try increasing the session duration and do the import again.

Comment: thank you so much! i'll increase the session duration and report back :)